# jsonObject.addProperty Method is adding unnecessary Quotation Marks and Slashes to it's value

Tags: android, string, json

**This is my String**

```
String currentTokenNo = "/SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==\nLmmWtgHZ90yH0NBoATYB/A"
```

**I've Added This String to my `JsonObject` which is a class of [com.google.gson.JsonObject](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html)  package**

```
  JsonObject jsonToSubmit = new JsonObject();

    try {

        jsonToSubmit.addProperty("token", currentTokenNo);

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

**But when I Log my `String` and `JsonObject`**

```
Log.d("mainactivityjson", "Current Token No : "+currentTokenNo );
Log.d("mainactivityjson", "jsonToSubmit : "+jsonToSubmit);
```

**I found the result**

```
D/mainactivityjson: Current Token No : "/SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==\nLmmWtgHZ90yH0NBoATYB/A"
D/mainactivityjson: jsonToSubmit : {"token":"\"/SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==\\nLmmWtgHZ90yH0NBoATYB/A\""}
```

**Now, My question is :**

Why those quotation marks and slashes are added to value of `JsonObject`? Is there any suitable reason of it ?

It is really hampering the process of checking String's value at server side.

**I've Done a temporary solution to accomplish the task by trimming single character from both side like following**

```
jsonToSubmit.addProperty("token",currentTokenNo.substring(1,currentTokenNo.length()-1));
```

This worked Perfectly But I don't think It's a better idea for future !!!

**Additional Information :**

Variable `currentTokenNo` is not declared directly as shown above, It was retrieved from `SharedPreferences` & If it is declared directly then everything works fine.

```
String currentTokenNo = preferences.getString(LOGINCRED_TOKEN,"");
```

If the same variable is declared directly, Everything works fine.

**Any kind of help will be appreciated.**

Comment: Are you sure `currentTokenNo` variable is declared as `String` ?

Comment: @miensol yes I'm sure !!! It's generated encrypted form of string..

Comment: What kind of string type are you passing? Do char, const char, something like that? Also do you have any encoding like UTF8 or dorm thing pointed on it anywhere?

Know that's a weird question just getting more of an understanding of what you're passing

Comment: it tries to escape the slashes which is legit.

Comment: @k0sh I know it is trying to escape characters but could not find out why quotation marks are added to It..

Comment: My logcat when using your code: `01-07 23:18:21.490 1619-1619/com.example.gsonitunes D/mainactivityjson: Current Token No : /SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==
                                                                        LmmWtgHZ90yH0NBoATYB/A
01-07 23:18:21.490 1619-1619/com.example.gsonitunes D/mainactivityjson: jsonToSubmit : {"token":"/SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==\nLmmWtgHZ90yH0NBoATYB/A"}`

Comment: @BNK so that I am telling if we declare string directly everything works fine brother. ..

Comment: Can you post logcat by using `Log.d("mainactivityjson", "Current Token No : "+currentTokenNo ); `right after `String currentTokenNo = preferences.getString(LOGINCRED_TOKEN,"");`?

Comment: @BNK `Current Token No "/SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==y9iWl1SSrUe9zRQppENMNA"`.. Sorry for previous Token No. It was replaced. But problem appears only after adding it to `jsonObject`.

Comment: As you can see, the value from SharedPreferences has had quotation marks already, so if directly used, it must be `String currentTokenNo = "\"/SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==y9iWl1SSrUe9zRQppENMNA\"";`

Comment: You can see in my previous comment `Current Token No : /SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw== LmmWtgHZ90yH0NBoATYB/A` (no quotation mark) :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100125/discussion-between-shree-krishna-and-bnk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments and logcat info, the actual value getting from `SharedPreferences`  is `"/SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==y9iWl1SSrUe9zRQppENMNA"` (having quotation marks), not `/SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==y9iWl1SSrUe9zRQppENMNA`. That's why you got `jsonToSubmit : {"token":"\"/SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==y9iWl1SSrUe9zRQppENMNA\""}`

---

**UPDATE:**

> For your temporary solution:
>   `jsonToSubmit.addProperty("token",currentTokenNo.substring(1,currentTokenNo.length()-1));`

I prefer the following way:

```
jsonToSubmit.addProperty("token", currentTokenNo.replaceAll("\"",""));
```

If you also want to remove slashes, then use:

```
jsonToSubmit.addProperty("token", currentTokenNo.replaceAll("\"","").replaceAll("/",""));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: If so then how to save  String to SharedPreferences without quatation marks.

Comment: If you can look at the SP's xml file, you will see something as the following `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<string name="token">_bcfPG5ToPzecCGxrosgA6AKNHgdfieuKEXxmQZUz-9ACg</string>
<string name="username">abc@xyz.com</string>
</map>`

Comment: And I think you should check the original value of the token, I mean that you check the code that generates and/or reponses the token

Comment: Hi! Have you checked as I commented?

Comment: Yes I've. Will my temporary solution works for future then.

Comment: I have messaged in chat !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100435/discussion-between-shree-krishna-and-bnk).

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you get in your logcat is correct.

Below are few points and reason why that happen so:

1) Unnecessary slashes added to your token. Why? Because your token contains back slash (\) that is an escaping character. So to it will be written as double slash (\\) instead of single slash (\).

2) Unnecessary quotation mark added to your token. Why? Again, your token is an String object and starts with a quotation ("). So it will be written as \".

So the overall you token changes from `"/SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==\nLmmWtgHZ90yH0NBoATYB/A"` to `"\"/SUeSjUf0A0aLFr+wVIZbw==\\nLmmWtgHZ90yH0NBoATYB/A\""`. But you need not to worry as whenever you will get your token data from `JsonObject`, you will always get the same token which you were added.

For more info about escape character, see here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 0):

It is some time after you posted this, but why not use `org.json.JSONObject` instead?

You wouldn't need to do that troublesome removal of unnecessary quotation marks and slashes removal.

Except if you try to do something like adding `yourJsonObject.toString()`into another *JSONObject*.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past this problem by changing how the originating string was created, using `getAsString()` instead of `toString()` when pulling the string from another JsonObject.

When debugging, the String would quote as expected until inserted into the new JsonObject.  Using the substring method above worked until I found to use `getAsString()`.

```
String ref = jsonObject.get("_ref").toString();  // ""\"url.local\"""
```

whereas

```
String ref = jsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString();  // ""url.local""
```

Adding in case it helps someone searching this old issue.